# Xamarin Build Canceled Not able to run

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have just installed Visual Studio 2019 with Xamarin and created a new blank app.

When I try to run the app, I have the following error :

> Starting emulator pixel_xl ...
>   Emulator pixel_xl cannot be started.
>   Runtime checks completed
>   NuGet package restore canceled.
>   Build has been canceled.

But while trying to building the solution, the solution builds successfully without error
I'm really new to Xamarin. Does anyone know how to solve this issue please.

Thanks

Comment: try  to create a new simulator to run,see if still have error

Comment: Maybe you can try to deploy the app to the real device.
Plug in your phone(enable USB debugging before in Developer settings) and check if it is recognized in VS.
If yes, it should display device name(or part of it) and then run the app on your device.

Comment: I am able to recognize physically connected device and able to run on it